# If javap output is inappropriate for jasmin, what's the alternative?

Tags: java, jasmin

I need something to replace only one method in a class. jd-gui/jad often produce broken code, that may even compile, but have undefined behavior.

This is why I need something to decompile classes into assembly language suitable for jasmin, so after recompilation they're no different from the original classes.

Comment: So what is your actual, concrete, problem?

Comment: @EJP I need to decompile a class, recompile it back and be sure that the only changes in it are those I made myself

Comment: I could use smali/backsmali, but it seems perverted, because I'd have to first convert jar to dex

Comment: All these disassemblers are too old. The latest is code.google.com/p/classfileanalyzer from 2009

Answer (score 0):

There's an old project called Jasper that can disassemble into Jasmin syntax. But what you really want is [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau). Krakatau uses a syntax which is similar to Jasmin, but updated in order to fix bugs and support more features. Unlike Jasmin, Krakatau supports every classfile feature,  and has both a disassembler and an assemler, making it easy to edit classes like you want.